# Detect if clients are connected to a network share

Tags: samba, nfs, network-share

we're running samba and nfs servers on an Ubuntu LTS 04.10 machine. Is there a way detect on the server, whether any client is connected to one of the shares? The clients are Windows 7,Linux or OS X systems.

I would like to know this in order to restart the server without disturbing my users.

Thanks, 
Kathrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use smbstatus for the Samba shares . It will print a list of users connected with machine, share, etc...

```
PID     Username      Group         Machine 

-------------------------------------------------------------------
  870   username1     Domain Users  machine1       (111.11.11.111)

  586   username2     Domain Users  machine2       (111.12.11.112)
```

With nfs, you can use showmount for a list of machines and mounted shares in the machine:

```
showmount

Hosts on server.domain.com:

111.11.0.0/16,machine1.domain.com

111.11.0.0/16,machine2.domain.com

111.11.0.0/16,machine3.domain.com
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Bruno

Comment: smbstatus is nice. Just wondering why I haven't found it myself. It just does not show mounts done via OS X. But the more important ones are there. With showmount I somehow see more mounts than currently active. So, I need to have a look at the different options.

Comment: yes.. showmount shows also the mounts defined in /etc/exports...

Comment: As smbstatus and showmount solves my problems in about 98% of the cases, i have accepted this answer. The remaining 2% will be handled by walking to the corresponding offices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `netstat -tp | grep smbd` to see whether there were any open `smbd` connections.

```
tcp        0      0 lo-app-31:microsoft-ds      <ip address of the other machine>:49225 ESTABLISHED 17700/smbd
tcp        0      0 lo-app-31:microsoft-ds      <ip address of the other machine>:49222 ESTABLISHED 27256/smbd
```

If they are `ESTABLISHED` then a machine is connected to `smbd` using TCP.